# Powershell parse a line from a text file and save to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I am fairly new to PS and have a need for what I am sure is a simple script. I have tried a few different ways without much luck.

I want to be able to run the script against a list of computer names such as c:\scripts\Computers.txt. From there I would like it to search for a text file on the computer and parse in the data of the workstation ID line. In the example below, it is WorkStationID=skapp1.

Once the workstation ID is captured, i'd like to save it in a row in a CSV file along with the computer name that it came from.

The remote file path that the text file is located in would be c$\iSeries\ACSC.ws (yes the file type is a .ws but it is viewable as txt)

======Start of file====

```
[Profile]
ID=WS
Version=9
[CT]
trace=Y
[Telnet5250]
HostName=MVPI01
AssociatedPrinterStartMinimized=N
AssociatedPrinterClose=N
AssociatedPrinterTimeout=0
Security=CA400
SSLClientAuthentication=Y
CertSelection=AUTOSELECT
[Communication]
Link=telnet5250
Session=5250
[5250]
HostCodePage=037-U
WorkStationID=skapp1
PrinterType=IBM3812
[Keyboard]
CuaKeyboard=2
Language=United-States
IBMDefaultKeyboard=N
DefaultKeyboard=C:\iSeries\AS400.KMP
[Window]
ViewFlags=CE00
CaptionFormat=225 -
UserTitle=ACSC
RuleLinePos=0 0
[LastExitView]
A=3 2014 92 976 610 3 12 20 400 0 IBM3270— 37

[printers]
printer=\\cntps01\IT,winspool,192.168.14.26
CPI=10
LPI=6
FaceName=[BatangChe]
Raster=N
Drawer1Orient=Portrait
Drawer2Orient=Portrait
VTPrintArea=Scroll
VTPrintChar=ASCII
VTTerminator=None

======End of file====
```

Can someone help me get a jump on this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following provided your executing account has access to the `c$` share on all of the systems:

```
Get-Content C:\scripts\Computers.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $FilePath = '\\{0}\c$\iSeries\ACSC.ws' -f $_
    $WorkStationId = (Get-Content $FilePath) -match 'WorkStationID=' -replace 'WorkStationID='
    [pscustomobject]@{Computer = $_; WorkStationID = [string]$WorkStationId}
} | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

Comment: That works perfectly and collects the data needed. Now to get the script to save to CSV :)

Comment: that would be easy.
Add $objectlist=@();
In the loop 
$objectlist += [pscustomobject]@{Computer = $_; WorkStationID = $WorkStationId}

finally outside of the loop, see manual for Export-CSV cmdlet
$objectlist | Export-CSV

Comment: @skapp I just updated the code to output to `output.csv`

Comment: @AdminOfThings it writes the CSV file now but for the WorkStationID column it's listing System.Object[] for each row. The Computer name is correct in Column A. If I run the script minus the CSV export, all data is correct on screen.

Comment: @skapp if there's only one workstationid in each file, my edit should fix it.